# How do I prevent the "Rich" Python library from printing "new_val" on startup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rich

The first time an attribute of rich is executed, `new_val` get's printed onto my console. This happens on quite a few attributes I have tried. For example, simply executing
`from rich.console import Console`
would result in `new_val` being printed.

The most perplexing part of this is that when I dug into the source code of Rich, I could not find "new_val" anywhere in `__init__.py` or `console.py`.

Has anyone encountered this before and how can I stop this?

System info:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Python 3.11.4
Rich 13.4.1
```

## Minimal, reproducible examples

Case 1:

```
from rich.console import Console
```

Case 2:

```
from rich import print
print('Hi')
```

### Expected output

Case 1:
Nothing

Case 2:
`Hi`

### Observed output

Case 1:
`new_val`

Case 2:

```
new_val
Hi
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. My guess is the issue is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: There is no other code. I ran only that one line on a fresh install of Python.

Comment: It must be something wrong with my system then hmm.

Comment: Try the line again in a new python shell.

Comment: @TheTridentGuy Tried it in a new directory. Seems to have fixed the problem. TY. I wonder what caused it.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer, don't edit it into the question.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Will do. Although I still have not fully figured it out as I still have no idea why Rich executed `attr.py`

Comment: Alternatively, incorporate your findings as part of the question, but in a coherent way, without adding "edit1", "edit 2" etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been caused by a conflicting file in that directory. I had a file named `attr.py` and in that file I had a line `t.add_val_to_a('new_val')`. When I deleted that file the issue went away. The question now becomes why did Rich access that seemingly completely unrelated file and why did the function `add_val_to_a` which is defined on a custom class have that effect on the execution of Rich?